# How to list docker containers that are not running in kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes

For dev/testing, I am running a few docker containers outside the (single node) k8s cluster in the same machine. Is it possible to list down/watch running containers from docker directly but not from k8s pods?

Edit 1: Using docker runtime in the Kubernetes.

Comment: What container runtime is your cluster using?

Comment: @Paolo, docker runtime

Comment: In a typical Kubernetes setup, I wouldn't expect to either be able to log in to a Node directly or to be able to run `docker` commands there.  How is your application using this information?  Can you restructure your code to not need to directly access the container runtime?

Comment: When I do `docker container ls` it lists all containers including those that are running through k8s. Is there a way to not show k8s containers? I can see k8s containers name start with `k8s_`

Comment: ohh, okay, got it.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `watch 'docker container ls | grep -v k8s_'`.

`grep -v` selects the non-matched lines.